# Using Android to display tweets by parsing JSON off a given JSON array

Tags: android, json, parsing, twitter

Following the tutorial blog post on http://www.heath-bar.com/blog/?p=599, I was able to get the JSON array for a user's timeline in my Android application. I understand tweets have a key of "text" but the data I have is nested and there are multiple tweets.

What is the most reasonable way to parse through the JSON array (currently a String) to get all the tweet text only?

Comment: Paste your JSONArray which you want to Parse

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> tweetlist = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i =0;i<i<yourjsonarray.lengh();i++)
{
String tweet =yourjsonarray.getjsonobject(i).getstring("text");
tweetlist.add(tweet);
}
```